# Intersection of two parametric lines

Tags: parametric

This is not a question on my homework, just one from the book I'm trying to figure out. They want me to find the intersection of these two lines:
\begin{align}
L_1:x=4t+2,y=3,z=-t+1,\\
L_2:x=2s+2,y=2s+3,z=s+1.
\end{align}
But they do not provide any examples. Flipping to the back it tells me that they do intersect and at the point $(2,3,1).$ How did they arrive at this answer? I'm just hoping to understand because I cannot derive any answer.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: set $4t+2 = 2s+2,$ $3 = 2s+3,$ $-t+1=s+1$ and find both $s$ and $t$ and then check that it all worked correctly.

Answer (score 4):

They intersect each other when all their coordinates are the same.

If we call $L_1=\langle x_1,y_1,z_1\rangle$ and $L_2=\langle x_2,y_2,z_2\rangle$ then you have to solve the system:
$$x_1=x_2\Longrightarrow4t+2=2s+2,$$
$$y_1=y_2\Longrightarrow3=2s+3,$$
$$z_1=z_2\Longrightarrow1-t=s+1.$$

In this case, if we set both parameters equal to zero, the system will be solved.
$$x_1=x_2\Longrightarrow2=2,$$
$$y_1=y_2\Longrightarrow3=3,$$
$$z_1=z_2\Longrightarrow1=1.$$

The system is solved for $t=0=s$. When you plug $t=0$ in $L_1$ you get $\langle 2,3,1\rangle$. The same happens when you plug $s=0$ in $L_2$.

Comment: Okay, so I have two unknowns, and three equations. So for the first one I find the relation that $2s=4t\implies s=2t$. How does this then allow me to find anything?

Comment: @bd1251252 take a look at the second equation. This gives you the answer straightaway!

Comment: Doesn't this just tell me $s=0$?

Comment: The only thing I see is that if the end numbers on $s$, i.e. if $s=0$, are (2,3,1) just like the answer. But I don't see how this gives me a point of intersection.

Comment: @bd1251252 The two lines intersect when they have the same values. That's why we need to check the values for $t$ and $s$ at which $x_1=x_2,y_1=y_2,z_1=z_2$.